# How to denormalize hierarchy in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, hierarchical-data, denormalization

I am new to ElasticSearch and I have a tree, which describes a path to a certain document (not real filesystem paths, just simple text fields categorizing articles, images, documents as one). Each path entry has a type, like.: `Group Name`, `Assembly name` or even `Unknown`. The types could be used in queries to skip certain entries in the path for example.

My source data is stored in SQL Server, the schema looks something like this:
[image]

Tree builds up by connecting the `Tree.Id` to `Tree.ParentId`, but each node must have a type. The Documents are connected to a leaf in the Tree.

I am not worried about querying the structure in SQL Server, however I should find an optimal approach to denormalize and search them in Elastic. If I flatten the paths and make a list of "descriptors" for a document, I can store each of the Document entries as an Elastic Document.:

```
{
  "path": "NodeNameRoot/NodeNameLevel_1/NodeNameLevel_2/NodeNameLevel_3/NodeNameLevel_4",
  "descriptors": [
    {
      "name": "NodeNameRoot",
      "type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "name": "NodeNameLevel_1",
      "type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "name": "NodeNameLevel_2",
      "type": "type2"
    },
    {
      "name": "NodeNameLevel_3",
      "type": "type2"
    },
    {
      "name": "NodeNameLevel_4",
      "type": "type3"
    }
  ],
  "document": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Can I query such a structure in ElasticSearch? Or Should I denormalize the paths in a different way?

My main questions:

Can query them based on type or text value (regex matching for example). For example: Give me all the type2->type3 paths (practically leave the type1 out), where the path contains `X`?

Is it possible to query based on levels? Like I would like the paths where there are 4 descriptors.

Can I do the searching with the built-in functionality or do I need to write an extension?

**Edit**
Based on G Quintana 's anwser, I made an index like this.:

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:9200/test \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "path": {
      "properties": {
        "names": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "tokens": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "pathname_analyzer"
            },
            "depth": {
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "pathname_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "types": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "tokens": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "pathname_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "pathname_analyzer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "#->>",
          "lowercase": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And could query the depth like this.:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:9200/test/path/_search \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"match": { "names.depth": 5 }}
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

Which return correct results. I will test it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should identify all your query patterns to design how you will index your data.

From the example you gave, I would index documents of the form:

```
{
  "path": "NodeNameRoot/NodeNameLevel_1/NodeNameLevel_2/NodeNameLevel_3/NodeNameLevel_4",
  "types: "type1/type1/type2/type2/type3",
  "document": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Before indexing, you must configure mapping and analysis:

- Field `path`:

  - use type `text` + analyzer based on [pattern analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) to split at `/` characters
  - use type [`token_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html) + same analyzer to compute path depth. Create a [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) (`path.depth`)
- Field `types`

  - use type `text` + analyzer based on [pattern analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) to split at `/` characters

Configure index mappings and analysis to split the `path` and `types` fields and the , use a  or a

1. *Give me all the type2->type3 paths* use a `match_phrase` query on the `types` field
2. *where the path contains X* use `match` query on the `path` field
3. *where there are 4 descriptors* use `term` query on `path.depth` sub field

Your descriptors field is not interesting.
The [Path tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) might be interesting for some usecases. 
You can apply multiple analyzer on the same field using [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and then query if sub fields.

Comment: I edited my question with the solution you suggested. It seems to work, but I wonder if you would have done it the same.

Comment: Also, to achieve `If at depth n field's text matches X`, I should introduce another field, which has the levels pointing to the node texts, like `"0":"NodeNameRoot"` and `"3":"NodeNameLevel_3"`